# prod build with lazyloading and no minification/uglify?

Tags: angular-cli, bundling-and-minification, froala

I'm using latest Angular CLI and having trouble with a third-party library crashing with prod builds (Froala.com specifically). It appears to be a problem when Froala gets minified/uglified with the rest of my project.

Is there a way I can specify this library to be lazy loaded and not minified? This would let me minify my entire application except the Froala library and thus not crash the app.